# IHttpHanlder returns null session

Tags: c#, httphandler, session-state

So i have a couple of custom Http Handlers for different file types. I have implemented the IRequiredSessionState marker, but still recieving context.Session as null?

Do you need to initialize the Session somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled session in your `Web.config` file? No, you don't need to perform any particular initialization:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" />
```

By the way, the interface name is `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState`, not `IRequiredSessionState`.

Comment: Didn't think i need to add extras to the web config. as my session state worked in other sections of the application. Will check it, thanks!

Comment: is this all? <pages enableSessionState="true">

was already set to true?

Comment: No, you need to enable it with `<sessionState>` element. `<pages>` element applies to ASPX pages only.

Comment: Are you sure you're testing the correct build of the application and not some older version without `IRequiresSessionState`?

Comment: yip. Should i not decorate the handlers in the config file with an enableSessionState or something?

Comment: No. Nothing else is needed.  Can you provide some context about how you're currently doing it? Are you messing with HTTP modules too?

Comment: No just http handler. Is it maybe because i'm posting to it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I suggest creating a new empty project and testing a simple handler: `context.Response.Write(context.Session == null);` and altering it incrementally to see what's the issue.

Comment: Eureka! Move the app to IIS from the WebDev thingy, and whalah!

Comment: I admit WebDev Web server is weird sometimes but I'm sure it does support session state. Anyway, good to see it work.

Comment: AAAH!!! Dammit, now the production server is not doing anything... session object null again... why would IIS 6 not load the session state? have check and double checked the web.config and iis configs.